# Interpret backspaces in file

Tags: bash, shell, console

Is there a way to interpret/"execute" backspaces in a file/line using common bash commands? I have a console program which prints some stuff and than erases it using backspaces and finally writes the end result. What I actually want is the output at the end.

```
echo -e "Foo\b\b\bBar" | what_goes_here > test.log
```

My test.log should only contain "Bar". I guess a problem to do this is how much text should be buffered until considered as really printed... In my case a "line buffered" interpreter would be sufficient.

Most utility have a switch which do not print such characters in first place. But the utility at hand has no such switch...

Comment: I really don't know what you want to do, could you try to make it clearer ? maybe add a concrete example  because is pretty confusing in my opinion

Comment: `echo -e "Foo\b\b\bBar" > test.log` works for me to have only `Bar` in test.log. Can you elaborate why this does not work for you?

Comment: @Bernhard Try: `od -c < test.log`

Comment: @Scrutinizer Clear, my text-editor also shows `^H`

Comment: @Bernhard then your text editor "interprets" the backspaces for you. I want a clean text file, only Bar (check `hexdump -C test.log`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what `col -b` is for:

```
$ printf 'a\bb\n' | col -b | od -tc
0000000   b  \n
0000002

$ printf 'aaa\b\b\bbb\n' | col -b | od -tc
0000000   b   b   a  \n
0000004
```

The `sed` equivalent would be something like:

```
bs=$(printf '\b')
sed "s/^[^$bs]*/&\
\
/;:1
s/\n.\{0,1\}\(.*\n\)\([^$bs]\)/\2\
\1/;s/\(.\{0,1\}\)\n\(.*\n\)$bs/\
\1\2/;t1
s/\n//g"
```

Dating to the times of the real tele-typewriters (tty), the `x\bx` sequence is sometimes found to represent a bold `x` (`x` typed over itself), `x\b_` or `_\bx` for an underlined `x` (`x̲`), and `x\b-` or `-\bx` for strike-through (`x̶`).

Another useful command to deal with those is the `colcrt` command.

```
$ printf '_\bfo\b_o\b_ bar b\b-a\b-z\b-\n' | colcrt
foo bar baz
---
```

Another option is to convert `\b_` and `\b-` to the Unicode combining characters U+0332 and U+0336:

Here assuming a Unicode locale and `zsh`, `ksh93` or `bash`:

```
$ printf 'f\b_o\b_o\b_ bar b\b-a\b-z\b-\n' | sed $'s/\b_/\u0332/g;s/\b-/\u0336/g'
f̲o̲o̲ bar b̶a̶z̶
```

(pipe to `colcrt` or `col -b` to also handle the `x\bx` bold).

Comment: +1: Had forgotten about that one :) . One would expect it to be part of POSIX, but apparently it was left out (but allowed as an "extension") on the basis that "No utilities defined in POSIX.1-2008 produce output requiring such a filter"

Answer (score 5):

Try `sed`

if used in `ksh93/zsh/bash`

```
printf "Foo\b\b\bBar\n" | sed -e :a -e "s/.\{0,1\}"$'\b'"//;ta" > test.log
```

or more portable

```
printf "Foo\b\b\bBar\n" | sed -e :a -e "s/.\{0,1\}$(printf "\b")//;ta" > test.log
```

or
 GNU sed:

```
printf "Foo\b\b\bBar\n" | gsed -re ":a;s/.?\x08//;ta" > test.log
```

---

Note: this approach treats '\b' as a backward erase instead of a backspace, so there would be a difference if the number of characters after a number of \b is less than the number of \b. (Thanks @StephaneChazelas )

Comment: This not interpreting backspaces - this is removing them via regex.

Comment: @mikeserv . Indeed, I hopefully clarified it by redirecting the examples to an output file..

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing it with stty, but I can't figure it out - there are too many options and it's over my head - I know it can be done I just don't know how. Anyway, this absolutely works - and I removed my downvote. But if you can figure out to read and write the tty after it's been interpreted reliably, I'll definitely upvote. Nevermind, have one anyway.

Comment: Note that it turns `ab\b` into `a` instead of `ab`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas . But that is what should happen, no? Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: `col -b` turns it into `ab`. `\b` doesn't delete, it moves the cursor backward. `aa\b\bb` should become `ba`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Point taken thanks, so yes there would be a difference if the number of characters after a number of `\b` is less than the number of `\b`. Thanks...